# php shell_exec() skipping python script

Tags: php, python, apache2, shell-exec

Working on Apache 2 web server on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I use `shell_exec()` to run a shell script.

It runs all the scripts except the parts where I run a python scripts eg. `python pythonscript.py`

When I run the shell script from the terminal it works just fine.

Any idea on how I could fix this? Could it be something related to permissions?

Cheers

Comment: just wondering.. why are you using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: Make sure the user that's running apache (which normally is www-data on Ubuntu) has permission to execute the file. You should also make sure to use absolute paths since that user doesn't have the same environment variables as your "normal" user. Something like: `/path/to/python /path/to/pythonfile.py`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I changed to absolute paths but still no change. Do you think I would have to grant acces to /usr/bin/python ?